# Phalcon\Mvc\Model's afterFetch

Tags: php, phalcon

say I have:

```
class Book extends Model
{
    private $someVar = 1;

    public function afterFetch()
    {
        if ($this->var == 2) $this->doSomething();
    }

    public function setVar($val)
    {
        $this->someVar = $val;
    }

    public function doSomething(){}
}

$book = Book::find($someId);
```

Question: how can I, in the above scenario, get *$this->someVar* to be equal to **2** in afterFetch() ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If `find` is a static method, then you don't have many options to alter that var outside of your scope, the only way i see is:

```
class Book extends Model
{
    private static $someVar = 1;

    public function afterFetch()
    {
        if (self::$someVar == 2) $this->doSomething();
    }

    public static function setVar($val)
    {
        self::$someVar = $val;
    }

    public function doSomething(){}
}

Book::setVar(2);
$book = Book::find($someId);
```

But again, i never used this framework, so there might be ways around this.

Answer (score 0):

The only time i see the afterfetch method trigger is when i do a findfirst

the only workaround i have found is to make a new function in the model that will iterate over the data . and run your functions.

i was hoping that find would actually run this code after as i was using query before but alas, i was wrong.

i would love to find a better solution but the best i can find is making a new method that acts like the afterfetch and is called manually.